# Unit test for httppostfilebase throws an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, viewmodel, httppostedfilebase

I am using httppostfilebase in form which is present in my viewmodel as:

```
   public HttpPostedFileBase details { get; set;}
```

My test is on service to repository and I want to test the Form data which is bonded with viewmodel, with fileupload. But, it throws this error:

> The type initializer for 'Moq.Mock`1' threw an exception.

Below is the testing code:

```
  public void TestMethod1()
        {

            var get = getservice();
            VSettlement ne = new VSettlement();//vm
            ne.name = " N LTD";
            ne.Settle_date = new DateTime(2017, 4, 26);
            ne.sAmount = 0;
            ne.SPerct = 0;
            ne.kCharges = 0;
            ne.AAmount = 0;
            ne.AmountReceived = 88500;


            var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
            file.Setup(x => x.FileName).Returns("NLTD-52.xlsx");
            ne.details = file.Object;(httppostfilebase in viewmodel)
            var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            server.Setup(x => x.MapPath("~/trax.Tests")).Returns(@"C:\Users\Development Team\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\trax.Tests");
            var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            httpContext.Setup(x => x.Server).Returns(server.Object);
            VReceipt pay = new VReceipt();//vm
            pay.AccountID = 1032;
            pay.Amount = 88500;
            pay.PaymentDate=new DateTime(2017, 4, 26);
            pay.PaymentModes = new SelectList("Cash");
            pay.Accounts = new SelectList("CHENNAI CASH");
            // act
            int? s = 0;
          var res=  get.Add(ne, pay, 1012, out s);
            Assert.IsTrue(res);


        }
```

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Which line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: **ne.details = file.Object** throws this error

Comment: I can recreate your code as far as setting ne.details to the mock object and I can assert that the file names are same... but I can't get it to error. What type is ne.details?

Comment: it is a viewmodel

Comment: Looking at your code...  ne = new VSettlement(); Which is your view model.. your assigning the mock to ne.details.. what type is the property "details" on your view model. Ah.. I can see in the post at the top1 :)

Comment: Sorry.. i just can't re-create the error.

Comment: np thank you for helping